# How to set object name and parameters from UI in python

Tags: python, arrays, object, parameters

I am working on a simple web app for a course project which is a basic travel tracker.
The user can enter the departure date, destination, airline and return date. The user will enter multiple trips.
This UI is saved to a txt file.
As part of the project, I have to also use classes. The chosen class is Trips and the parameters are the UI. 
I have then built a countdown to show the time to or since the departure date. I want this to use the class object and parameter.
I am looking for a way to automate the object name and parameters from the UI.
Below is the code and line 24 shows the line I hope to achieve automatically.

```
import datetime

#set class
class Trips:
    def __init__(self, destination, dep_date, airline, ret_date):
        self.destination = destination
        self.dep_date = dep_date
        self.airline = airline
        self.ret_date = ret_date

#get trips
def get_trips():
    tripsdb = open("tripsdb.txt")
    content = tripsdb.read()
    tripsdb.close()
    trips = content.split("$$$")
    trips.pop(len(trips)-1)
    return trips

#countdown days to departure using datetime
def countdown():

    trips = get_trips()
    trip1 = Trips(*trips[2].split(",")) #need to automate

    get_date = trip1.dep_date

    depart_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(get_date, "%d.%m.%Y")
    #set todays date
    nowdate = datetime.datetime.now()
    #difference in seconds
    count = int((depart_date-nowdate).total_seconds())
    #divide into days
    days = count/86400
    # set as int to round and string to concatenate, use abs to remove "-"
    if int(days) > 0:
        return(str(int(days)) + " days left to departure")
    elif int(days) == 0:
        return "You depart today!"
    else:
        return (str(abs(int(days))) + " days since your departure") 

print(countdown())
```

I have tried all sorts with loops and zips but keep getting stuck with all sorts of errors depending on what I was trying. I attempted to create an array using a for loop through the length of trips which would return trip_num = [trip0, trip1, trip2] so that I would get the variable names.

```
def get_array():
    array = []
    num = -1
    trips = get_trips()
    for trip in trips:
        num += 1
        array += ["trip " + str(num)]
    return array

trip_num = get_array()
```

Then I wanted to concatenate basically the first item in **trip_num** to the first item of **trips** to return something along the lines of **trip1=destination, dep_date, airline, ret_date** and so on for each. See what I mean?

Comment: first you should show error which you get. We can't run your code and we can't read in your mind to see these errors.

Comment: BTW: I would use name `Trip` because it can keep only one trip. And I would use `for`-loop to create many `Trip` which I would keep on list.

Comment: you can use `.pop(-1)` instead of `.pop(len(trips)-1)` to get last item

Comment: Ahhh @furas, I am disappointed in your lack of mind-reading ability! ;)
So I got several errors depending on what I was trying... I attempted to create an array using a for loop through the length of trips which would return trip_num = [trip0, trip1, trip2] so that I would get the variable names. Then I wanted to concatenate basically the first item in trip_num to the first item of trips to return something along the lines of trip1=destination, dep_date, airline, ret_date. 
See what i mean?

Comment: @furas, thanks also for the additional tips, I'm just starting out so I am at the stage where I just muddle along with the knowledge I have and hope for the best. Hopefully, I'll iron some of those faults out in time...

Comment: always put code, data and error messages in question (as text) - they will be more readable (in comment you can't format it) and more people will see them (people may not read comments) so you can get more answers.

Comment: @furas I have edited above, thanks

Comment: don't waste time for variable `trip1`, `trip2`, etc. put values on list/array and use `array[0]`, `array[1]` to get one trip. If you really want variables like `trip1`, `trip2` then you have dictionary for this - `data = dict()` , `data["trip1"] = value` and `print(data["trip1"])`

Comment: OK, so I wanted to get variables as I wanted to assign class roles and thought this would be the only way I could. I manually achieve this in my initial question where I write ```trip1 = Trips(*trips[2].split(","))``` Using the dictionary as you suggest would still need me to write "trip1" manually wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your problem but it is how I would write it.

- In class I convert both dates to `datetime` objects.
- I put `countdown` as method in class, not external function.
- I keep all trips on list without using variables `trip1`, `trip2`, etc.

.

```
# --- classes ---

class Trip:

    def __init__(self, destination, dep_date, airline, ret_date):
        self.destination = destination
        self.airline = airline
        self.dep_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dep_date, "%d.%m.%Y")
        self.ret_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(ret_date, "%d.%m.%Y")

    def countdown(self):
        nowdate = datetime.datetime.now()

        seconds = (self.dep_date-nowdate).total_seconds()
        days = seconds//86400 # divide and round to integer

        if days > 0:
            return "{} days left to departure".format(days)
        elif days < 0:
            return "{} days since your departure".format(-days) 
        else:
            return "You depart today!"

# --- functions ---

def read_trips():
    tripsdb = open("tripsdb.txt")
    content = tripsdb.read()
    tripsdb.close()

    trips = content.split("$$$")
    trips.pop(-1)
    #trips = content.split("$$$")[:-1] in one line using `slicing`

    # convert to list of objects Trip
    all_trips = []
    for trip in trips:
        all_trips.append( Trip(*trip.split(",")) )

    return all_trips

def write_trips(all_trips):
    pass
    #TODO: write it

# --- main ---

all_trips = read_trips()

for trip in all_trips:
    print('Destination:', trip.destination)
    print('Airline:', trip.airline)
    print('Countdown:', trip.countdown())
    print('---')
```

Comment: OOOHHH! @furas! You are a **legend!** ```.append! ```that is what I was missing! and the way you cleaned up the rest is brilliant. I had thought about putting the countdown in as a method so glad to see that in there too. Thank you so much!